# rails f.select - disabling an option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to be able to disable a select option that in essence can be used as a placeholder. :prompt does not seem to work for me as this is still a selectable option.

It html, what I want would be:

```
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option value="" disabled selected style='display:none;'>Difficulty</option>
  <option value="b">Beginner</option>
  <option value="i">Intermediate</option>
  <option value="a">Advanced</option>
</select>
```

In rails all I have is:

```
<%= f.select(:difficulty, [['Beginner', 1], ['Intermediate', 2], ['Advanced', 3]], {}, { :class => 'selectpicker' }) %>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chapster82/QL6D7/

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out but is this correct?

```
<%= f.select(:difficulty, [['Difficulty', '0'], ['Beginner', 1], ['Intermediate', 2], ['Advanced', 3]], {:disabled => 0, :selected => 0}, { :class => 'selectpicker' }) %>
```